# Best approach to extract 1000 Gbs of Data from Teradata

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, etl, teradata

What should be the best approach to download data from Teradata using python ? I have more than 3000 GBs of data to be migrated from teradata to another code service. Any approach or advise would be great.

So far I have explored -

1. Using Pandas it is slow and inefficient. I have also used {fn teradata_try_fastexport} but it seems to be no difference.
2. Using tdload I am not able to partition the file and no support for downloading file with byte,clob,blob data type.
3. Using dask, not able to connect with teradata and get the data using dask dataframe. I have read the sql using pandas and then use dask to write the data. However, that seems to be of little help in comparison to huge amount of data.
4. Pyspark - I am exploring but it seems difficult with too much file configuration and dependency issue.

Any advise or suggested approach that I should follow for the efficient and effective data extraction.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to see if the other service has migration tools. My second suggestion would be that perhaps [dba.se] might be a better fit for this question.

Comment: You should use Teradata's TPT EXPORT to export the data into a file or pipe and then the batch load utilities of "the other code service".